# How to find articles containing specific keywords such as "cosmology" in several scientific databases?

Tags: databases

I need to check articles containing specific keywords such as "cosmology" daily. It takes long time to search one by one search engines and databases such as ScienceDirect, GoogleScholar, arxiv, and similar ones.
Is there a service or application to search in all of these websites?

Answer (score 6):

[ScienceDirect](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/sciencedirect/support/sd-tutorials/create-and-save-alerts-on-sciencedirect), [Google Scholar](http://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=283150&p=1886381), and other publisher or database services allow you to save a search and have any new items matching that be emailed to you (though it may not always be within a day - I vaguely recall that I usually knew about PLOS or ScienceDirect papers before I got the email - often via the Google Scholar alert! Still fairly timely, though.)

arXiv allows you to get [a daily email](https://arxiv.org/help/subscribe) with all new papers in a specific subject category. I don't believe it supports keyword searching for alerts - however, one of those categories is cosmology, so it may work fine for you.